# Pansharpening of Spot 6 image

Tags: remote-sensing

Would the pansharpening of Spot 6 work on the NIR band? Since the wavelengths captured by the panchromatic band does not overlap with the NIR band. The band designations are in the attached image.

[image: Wavelength of Spot 6 spectral bands]